# Не работает коммерческое статическое АПИ яндекс.карт

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Какой ключ и как использовать для коммерческой версии Static API на вебсайте? Имеется коммерческая версия яндекс.карт, есть соответственно ключ (uuid). При использовании карты как карты все хорошо, при этом к ссылке на скрипт добавляется параметр apikey. При использовании же карты в виде картинки (коммерческое Static API на enterprise.static-maps.yandex.ru) с тем же самым ключом приходит ответ 401

`Key 'ХХХ...' is not allowed for requests from ХХХ`

при этом в параметрах уже надо указывать ?key=. Оба АПИ пробуются на том же самом домене, для одного ключ работает, а для другого - нет. Как картинку-то получить от статического апи в коммерческой версии?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы сами дали ответ в своём вопросе. "Использовали ключ **JS API** для **Static API**". Это разные сервисы, у них разные ключи и тарифы. Приобретение одной коммерческой лицензии не даёт вам доступа сразу ко всем другим геосервисам Яндекса. Приобретите [коммерческую лицензию Static API](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/commercial/doc/concepts/staticapi.html#staticapi__tariffs) и используйте в запросах новый полученный ключ.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения, не знал таких деталей.

Comment: Не за что. Вообще вопросы по лицензиям и ключам лучше сразу задавать в поддержку API Яндекс Карт - maps-api@support.yandex.ru Ситуация может потребовать их проверки или подключения к работе коммерческих менеджеров, а с этим тут никто помочь не сможет.